# What is the simples way to see if Twilio Chat Member/User/Client has unread messages?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm aware of the [Twilio Consumption Horizon](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/consumption-horizon) and its complexities (tracking by message index). This tracking is required in order for the [Channel.getUnconsumedMessagesCount()](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.0.0/docs/Channel.html#getUnconsumedMessagesCount__anchor) to work. This is a very powerful API but in my case, I need something **way more simple**.

I just need to see if User, Member or Channel has unread messages or not.

Is there a simple way to achieve this with *Twilio JS Client SDK* without implementing complex message consumption horizons?

Taking an iterative approach to our development, I really don't want or need a complex solution. Just to show I user has new messages in any of his channels or not.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the extra complexity is here. In order to know whether a member has unread messages you need to tell the SDK the last message the member did read (on a per channel basis). You don't have any calculations to do, you can either use `channel.setAllMessagesConsumed` to bring a member up to date or `channel.updateLastConsumedMessageIndex` to be specific. Note that all message objects include their index. How would you expect this to work with less complexity?

Comment: You would need to track each channel and set the last consumed message index before you can use the getUnconsumedMessagesCount(). Otherwise it returns null. The question was, if there is a way that the SDK does that for me. If not, then per channel message tracking is required.

Comment: No, the SDK can't do that for you because the SDK cannot know whether your user has read the message. Delivering a message to the SDK does not imply that it is read (or even shown on screen). So you do need to implement that.